# Can someone help clarify integer objects and a few other things

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I understand that everything in Python is an object. I also understand that an object is a portion of memory that contains information. Knowing these two things made me wonder how integers can be objects so I went digging.  I figured out that CPython creates a range from -5 to 256 on startup.

So, what I would like to know is whether or not this is correct as I can not find an answer.  `1` is an identifier that points to an object where the information stored in there is the value 1, is this statement correct?  Also, if CPython only creates a range from -5 to 256, then how do integers above or below that range know what value is being stored in them?  How do strings and floats know what value is being stored in them?

Sorry if this is a bad question, I am new to coding and trying to wrap my head around the terminology and understand what is happing when I execute lines of code. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If you are new to coding, I think you are looking too far into the details :)

Comment: Probably so, but I'm a curious person haha

Comment: I googled but so far no references to your magic numbers '-5' and '256'. "creates a range"... of what? Also, how CPython manages memory is both irrelevant and subject to change without notice. Unless you are a CPython developer.

Comment: @Muposat https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html this link is where I got those numbers from.

Comment: That means when you create an int in that range cpython just uses a  pointer to that value in their secret cache. For ints outside that range it actually allocates memory, writes down your int and uses a pointer to that memory to access your int. This is their internal optimization, both not-portable and subject to change.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is relevant for C API, which is a pretty advanced topic. I suggest knowing both Python and C before venturing into this territory.

Comment: The creation of numbers -5 to 256 is just an optimization to increase execution speed.   It is very likely that a lot of these numbers will be used in almost any python program, so the python interpreter does not have to allocate memory and create the objects when they are needed.  Have a look at "python garbage collector" (also look at Blckknght answer above)

Comment: @Muposat, thank you for the answer. I will take your advice and wait till later if I really wish to pursue this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers are objects because *everything* is an object. If you're wrapping your brain around the terminology bits, I'd recommend checking out the Everything Is an Object chapter in [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html). Here's the most relevant bit:

> Everything in Python is an object, and almost everything has attributes and methods. All functions have a built-in attribute `__doc__`, which returns the doc string defined in the function's source code. The `sys` module is an object which has (among other things) an attribute called `path`. And so forth.
>
> Still, this begs the question. What is an object? Different programming languages define “object” in different ways. In some, it means that all objects must have attributes and methods; in others, it means that all objects are subclassable. In Python, the definition is looser; some objects have neither attributes nor methods (more on this in Chapter 3), and not all objects are subclassable (more on this in Chapter 5). But everything is an object in the sense that it can be assigned to a variable or passed as an argument to a function (more in this in Chapter 4).

Answer (score 1):

All of Python integers are objects. Their values are a bit complicated, as they can expand to support very large numbers (bigger than the standard 32- or 64-bit integers available in most programming languages). The implementation is written in C, and you can find it [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/longobject.c). You don't really need to know or care about the details of the implementation though. The `int` objects work pretty much like every other kind of object in Python.

The caching of integers `-5` through `256` is a separate thing. The caching avoids recreating the same small integers over and over, but the cached `1` object is still the same kind of object as an uncached `int` like `257`. It's just that every time you have an `int` who's value is `1` you're dealing with the exact same object, while there may be several objects with the value `257` in existence at the same time. You can write your own classes that do this sort of caching if you want, just define a `__new__` method that returns a pre-existing instance of the class. The caching is another implementation detail that you don't really need to care about. Python would still work just fine if it didn't cache any integers (it just might be a little bit slower and use a bit more memory than the current cached implementation).